# Open file from desktop to a popupwindow

Tags: javascript, html, popupwindow

Im a total beginner at html coding and i was wondering if I can write window size and other properties directly into the page. 
Il explain.

Im working on a calc and I want to run the html file on my desktop. Everything works fine but it launches in the browser where other tabs are opened. I want it to run in a small popup window with no statusbars bookmarkbars with a fixed window size.

EDIT:

the code itself

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><center>Kalkuraatur</center>
<Title>Javascripti Kalkulaator</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(window.name != "mypopup") {
        window.open(document.location.href,'mypopup', 'left=300,top=200,width=200,height=200,toolbar=0,status=0,location=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,titlebar=0'); var child = window.open(...; child.focus();
        window.close();
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function arvuta ()
{
kalku.sisend.value = eval(kalku.sisend.value)
}
function Bspace(sisend)
{
kalku.sisend.value = kalku.sisend.value.substring(0, kalku.sisend.value.length - 1)
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form name="kalku">
<table border=2>
<tr><td>
<input type="text" name="sisend" size="21">
<br>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="button" name="seitse" value=" 7 " style="height: 22px; width: 30px" onclick="kalku.sisend.value += '7'">
<input type="button" name="kaheksa" value=" 8 " style="height: 22px; width: 30px" onclick="kalku.sisend.value += '8'">
<input type="button" name="yheksa" value=" 9 " style="height: 22px; width: 30px" onclick="kalku.sisend.value += '9'">
<input type="button" name="ykstagasi" value="del" style="height: 22px; width: 30px" onclick="Bspace(this)">
<input type="button" name="kustuta" value=" C " style="height: 22px; width: 30px" onclick="kalku.sisend.value = ''">
<br>
<input type="button" name="neli" value=" 4 " style="height: 22px; width: 30px" onclick="kalku.sisend.value += '4'">
<input type="button" name="viis" value=" 5 " style="height: 22px; width: 30px" onclick="kalku.sisend.value += '5'">
<input type="button" name="kuus" value=" 6 " style="height: 22px; width: 30px" onclick="kalku.sisend.value += '6'">
<input type="button" name="jaga" value=" ÷ " style="height: 22px; width: 30px" onclick="kalku.sisend.value += '/'">
<input type="button" name="korruta" value=" x " style="height: 22px; width: 30px" onclick="kalku.sisend.value += '*'">
<br>
<input type="button" name="yks" value=" 1 " style="height: 22px; width: 30px" onclick="kalku.sisend.value += '1'">
<input type="button" name="kaks" value=" 2 " style="height: 22px; width: 30px" onclick="kalku.sisend.value += '2'">
<input type="button" name="kolm" value=" 3 " style="height: 22px; width: 30px" onclick="kalku.sisend.value += '3'">
<input type="button" name="lahuta" value=" - " style="height: 22px; width: 30px" onclick="kalku.sisend.value += '-'">
<input type="button" name="plus" value=" + " style="height: 22px; width: 30px" onclick="kalku.sisend.value += '+'">
<br>
<input type="button" name="null" value=" 0 " style="height: 23px; width: 64px" onclick="kalku.sisend.value += '0'">
<input type="button" name="koma" value=" , " style="height: 22px; width: 30px" onclick="kalku.sisend.value += ','">
<input type="button" name="v6rdub" value=" = " style="height: 22px; width: 64px" onclick="arvuta ()">
</td></tr>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You would have to resort to JavaScript. Try http://www.textfixer.com/html/javascript-pop-up-window.php and see if that helps.

Comment: Calc as calculator and the file is not uploaded anywhere. its in my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to configure/deal with popup blockers, you could add this as the first entry to the head of your html document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(window.name != "mypopup") {
        window.open(document.location.href,'mypopup', 'left=300,top=200,width=200,height=200,toolbar=0,status=0,location=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,titlebar=0');
        window.open('', '_self', ''); // chrome bug
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

Haven't tested but try this for focus:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(window.name != "mypopup") {
        var childWindow = window.open(document.location.href,'mypopup', 'left=300,top=200,width=200,height=200,toolbar=0,status=0,location=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,titlebar=0');
        //like this
        childWindow.focus();
        window.open('', '_self', ''); // chrome bug
        window.close();
    } else {
        //or like this
        window.focus();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How can i set it to open on top?

Comment: you can call **focus()** on the child window, try creating else and putting it there as **window.focus()** or you can get assign the return of window.open function to a var like **var child = window.open(...; child.focus();**

Comment: I alowed chrome to open popups from my file but it doesn't open them. in ie i have to alow scripts but it is working. Thankyou very much.

Comment: I've edited your post to correct your paste error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the size of the browser window is something you cannot change with HTML. Now you could write your own popup using `javascript` and/or `jQuery`.

Add a "click to run calc" link to the page the user will land on. When they click the link launch your custom popup.

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/X732t/) of what I mean.

Comment: I allready got something like that, but I wanted it to instantly open the page in a window without having to click on something.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the window.open documentation on W3 to specify what you need.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp